# Unable to access PayPal from AWS EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, paypal

I'm unsure where to ask this as it touches upon Drupal, AWS, and PayPal. I've added a Drupal 7 site to an AWS EC2 instance I setup (using Ubuntu). I'm trying to get Drupal Commerce (specifically PayPal Payflow Link, if it matters) to work with my site. I've added my API credentials in the module (Partner, Merchant Login and User, and Password) but when the application tries to connect with PayPal I get this error:

```
"Communication with PayPal failed. Please try again or contact an administrator to resolve the issue."
```

Is there something I need to enable on EC2 (or Drupal) to allow communication to take place with PayPal (for example)...like a mail server or something?

Networking is not my strongest suit...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a firewall blocking access to PayPal's IP addresses.  You can [see their curent IPs here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1056&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en).  Make sure those are reachable through your server's network.